# cant convert lowercase to uppercase a string by preprocessor directive

Tags: c

i made a program which converts lower case to upper case a string.i know how to convert a char to upper case via preprocessor directives but i dont know how to do it for a string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define UPPER([])  ([]-32)
void fstring_convert(char string[]);
void main(void)
{
char string[40];
printf("Enter a string:");
gets(string);
fstring_convert(string);
printf("%s",string);
getch();
}

void fstring_convert(char string[])
{
    int i;
 for(i=0; ;i++)
 {
    if(string[i]==' ')
    {
        string[i]=string[i+1];
    }
    if(isdigit(string[i]))
    {
    string[i]+=1;
    }
    UPPER('string[i]');
    if(string[i]=='\0')
    break;
 }

}
```

Comment: IS that your homework assignment? To convert a string to uppercase with macros? Really?

Comment: Can't imagine that your bizarre attempt to `define` a macro named `UPPER` runs through the preprocessor. Please only post code that compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preprocessors do not have loops.

Thus, for a string of arbitrary length, you cannot convert all characters to upper case with a preprocessor macro.

The code you have above is buggy because your macro should look like:

```
#define TOUPPER(x) x = (x>='a' && x<='z')?(x-32):x;
```

And then call `TOUPPER(string[i])` in your `for` loop.

But I don't see what the point of the macro is.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the C standard library function `toupper()` on each character of the string (in a loop).  This function has the advantage of correctly handling non-alphabetic characters.

Comment: i am told to use preprocessor directives

Comment: @fahad:  That is a most unusual requirement.  There's always the option of `#define my_toupper(x) toupper(x)`.

Comment: you mean i can call a built in function within the preprocessor?

Comment: @fahad:  Do you know what the preprocessor does?  If not, you should consult your C book.

Answer (score 3):

This homework assignment is to teach you about ascii and type conversion.

Loop through the string one letter at a time. For each letter, lookup the ascii code for the letter, (find the offset to uppercase do this once while coding and store in a constant), then add the offset to the letter.

Hint: a char can be cast as an int.

Answer (score 2):

If you're assuming that you're dealing with ASCII, then you might as well take advantage of how the characters are laid out. To convert to upper case, do `c & ~0x20`. To convert to lower case, do `c | 0x20`.  To toggle between upper and lower case, `c ^ 0x20`. These basically amount to adding or subtracting 32 (== 0x20), but they are better in that applying them repeatedly does what you expect e.g. `toupper(toupper(c))` is upper case, instead of `c - 64` i.e. garbage.

Check out http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ascii.7.html, especially the hex table near the end. It clearly shows the relationship between different characters. There are some nice patterns, but I suspect that for historical reasons there are some unfortunate incongruences. For example, to convert between `[` and `]` or `{` and `}` you can just do 'c ^ 0x6', but between `(` and `)` it's different, and its different for `<` and `>` as well. However, it is still nonetheless possible to define a branch-free (i.e. no `if`s and such) expression to compute the matching delimiter of any given delimiter.